# Next Element in .each()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to go to the next element in jQuery .each()?

```
$(".row").each( function() {
    if ( ... ) 
        //go to next iteration in .each()
});
```

Thanks

Comment: You can call `return true` to continue to the next iteration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".row").each( function() {
    if ( ! ... ) {
        ... do everything else ...
    }
});
```

Or:

```
$(".row").each( function() {
    if ( ... ) 
        return; //go to next iteration in .each()
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var rows = $(".row").each( function(idx) {
    var nextRow = rows.eq(idx + 1);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You just need make a return to exit from anonymous function and go to next iteration.

```
$(".row").each( function() {
    if ( ... ) 
        return; //go to next iteration in .each()
});
```